# Cant keep above keyboard when using CupertinoDatePicker

Tags: flutter

I have some textFormFields inside a column and to avoid bottom overflow errors and automatically scroll above the keyboard I have it inside a SingleChildScrollView.

I added a CupertinoDatePicker and got a `RenderFlex object was given an infinite size during layout` error.

The only way I could fix that was to put the datepicker in a sized box

```
Widget _buildDatetime() {
  return SizedBox(
    height:200,
    child:
    CupertinoDatePicker(
    mode: CupertinoDatePickerMode.time,
    minuteInterval: 1,
    minimumDate: DateTime.now().subtract(Duration(days:1)),
    initialDateTime: DateTime.now(),
    onDateTimeChanged: (DateTime newdate) {
      print(newdate);
      //scrollController.animateTo(180.0,
     //     duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500), curve: Curves.ease);
    },
  )
  );
}
```

Now the SingleChildScrollView won't scroll my submit button above the keyboard and `resizeToAvoidBottomInset` doesn't work either.

I'm guessing its something to do with the fixed size of the datepicker but I can't find a way around it.

Here's my whole scaffold -

```
return Scaffold(
        body: Container(
          color: Color.fromRGBO(255, 255, 255, 1),
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 43.0),
          child: Form(
            key: _formKey,
            child: Container(
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              child: SingleChildScrollView( // new line
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      _buildFirstName(),
                      _buildSurname(),
                      _buildEmail(),
                      _buildPhone(),
                      _buildTableNumber(),
                      _buildDatetime(),
                      _buildSignUpButton(context)
                    ],
                  ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ));
```

Comment: Try wrapping the CupertinoDatePicker in Expanded

Comment: Instead of a `Column` inside a `SingleChildScrollView`, have you tried using a `ListView`?

Comment: I've tried ListView and Expanded now but either have the same issues or errors.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add a `padding` inside your `SingleChildScrollView`.

```
return Scaffold(
        body: Container(
          color: Color.fromRGBO(255, 255, 255, 1),
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 43.0),
          child: Form(
            key: _formKey,
            child: Container(
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              child: SingleChildScrollView( // new line
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom), //ADD PADDING HERE
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      _buildFirstName(),
                      _buildSurname(),
                      _buildEmail(),
                      _buildPhone(),
                      _buildTableNumber(),
                      _buildDatetime(),
                      _buildSignUpButton(context)
                    ],
                  ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ));
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: Thanks just gave this a go but still having the same issue.